# How to do offset on AVAudioPCMBuffer?

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation

I have `AVAudioPCMBuffer`, I set it as a source to the `AVAudioPlayerNode`

```
    internal func play() {
        guard let buf = pcmBuf else {
            logger?.log(severity: .error, msg: "Sound pcmBuf is nil.")
            return
        }
        
        if !isPlaying {
            player.scheduleBuffer(buf, at: nil, options: .loops)
            player.play()
        }
    }
```

It is possible that the user seeks forward, in order to do it I need to offset the buffer and set it again, like this

```
    internal func play() {
        guard let buf = pcmBuf else {
            logger?.log(severity: .error, msg: "Sound pcmBuf is nil.")
            return
        }

        buf.offset = 10 // Eg: in sec        

        if !isPlaying {
            player.scheduleBuffer(buf, at: nil, options: .loops)
            player.play()
        }
    }
```

So, it will look like I set a new buffer, but with the needed offset, and the playback will start from the required point.

The problem is that there is no `offset` method...

How to do it?

Comment: Where are your `AVAudioPCMBuffer`s coming from?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I create it from UnsafeRawPointer that I got from the native lib. So, the flow is native lib -> pointer -> convert to pcm buf -> use in node

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to offset the buffer. You should pass your play function a valid second parameter instead of nil.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioplayernode/1388422-schedulebuffer

"Schedules the playing samples from an audio buffer at the time and playback options you specify."

So pass in a valid AVAudioTime.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioplayernode#1669195

```
init(sampleTime: AVAudioFramePosition, 
atRate sampleRate: Double)
```

I am guessing this is probably the initialiser you want.

Comment: I am not sure about this, as far as I understood the way you described useful when I need to postpone the playback, for example, I need the music started to play in 5 seconds, so after the start, it will be played in 5 sec. But something I am looking for is offset in the song, for example track duration 20 sec and I need to start to play it from sec 5 to 20